# typeorm mariadb ER_PARSE_ERROR, no idea whats wrong

Tags: mariadb, typeorm

i am trying to save data using typeorm with mariadb driver. But I got this error:

```
error: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'In 1972, a popular student in Yomiyama North Middle School\'s class 3-3 named ' at line 1
    at Packet.asError (D:\kiramanga_fetch\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:722:17)
    at Query.execute (D:\kiramanga_fetch\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:28:26)
    at PoolConnection.handlePacket (D:\kiramanga_fetch\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:456:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (D:\kiramanga_fetch\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:85:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (D:\kiramanga_fetch\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\kiramanga_fetch\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:92:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10) {
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlState: '42000',
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
near ' 'In 1972, a popular student in Yomiyama North Middle School\\'s class 3-3 named ' at line 1",
  sql: 'INSERT INTO `Anime`(`id`, `anf_id`, `original`, `title`, `en_title`, `synonyms`, `synopsis`, `background`, `related`, `featured`, `url`, `show_type`, `status`, `source`, `episodes`, `songs`, `trailer`, `airing`, `airing_now`, `duration`, `rating`, `rate`, `update_time`, `seasonId`) VALUES (DEFAULT, \'11111\', \'アナザー\', \'Another\', \'Another\', , \'In 1972, a popular student in Yomiyama North Middle School\\\'s class 3-3 named Misaki passed away during the school year. Since then, the town of Yomiyama has been shrouded by a fearful atmosphere, from the dark secrets 
hidden deep within. Twenty-six years later, 15-year-old Kouichi Sakakibara transfers into class 3-3 of Yomiyama North and soon after discovers that a strange, gloomy mood seems to hang over all the students. He also finds himself drawn to the mysterious, eyepatch-wearing student Mei Misaki; 
however, the rest of the class and the teachers seem to treat her like she doesn\\\'t exist. Paying no heed to warnings from everyone including Mei herself, Kouichi begins to get closer not only to her, but also to the truth behind the gruesome phenomenon plaguing class 3-3 of Yomiyama North. Another follows Kouichi, Mei, and their classmates as they are pulled into the enigma surrounding a series of inevitable, tragic events—but unraveling the horror of Yomiyama may just cost them the ultimate price. [Written by MAL Rewrite]\', \'In 1972, a popular student in Yomiyama North Middle School\\\'s class 3-3 named Misaki passed away during the school year. Since then, the town of Yomiyama has been shrouded by a fearful atmosphere, from the dark secrets hidden deep within.Twenty-six years later, 15-year-old Kouichi Sakakibara transfers into class 3-3 of Yomiyama North and soon after discovers that a strange, gloomy mood seems to hang over all the students. He also finds himself drawn to the mysterious, eyepatch-wearing student Mei Misaki; however, the rest of the class and the teachers seem to treat her like she doesn\\\'t exist. Paying no heed to warnings from everyone including Mei herself, Kouichi begins to get closer not only to her, but also to the truth behind the gruesome phenomenon plaguing 
class 3-3 of Yomiyama North.Another follows Kouichi, Mei, and their classmates as they are pulled into the enigma surrounding a series of inevitable, tragic events—but unraveling the horror of Yomiyama may just cost them the ultimate price.[Written by MAL Rewrite]Pre-screening on 26 December 2011. The regular TV airing started on 09 January 2012.\', \'{\\"prequel\\":[{\\"anf_id\\":11701,\\"title\\":\\"Another: The Other - Inga\\",\\"url\\":\\"/anime/11701/another-the-other-inga\\"}],\\"adaptation\\":[{\\"anf_id\\":29699,\\"title\\":\\"Another\\",\\"url\\":\\"/manga/29699/another\\"}],\\"other\\":[{\\"anf_id\\":20365,\\"title\\":\\"Another: Misaki Mei - Shizukani\\",\\"url\\":\\"/anime/20365/another-misaki-mei-shizukani\\"}]}\', \'https://ik.imagekit.io/feedani/another\', \'/anime/11111/another\', \'TV\', \'Finished Airing\', \'Light novel\', 12, \'{\\"opening\\":[\\"\\\\\\"Kyoumu Densen (凶夢伝染)\\\\\\" by ALI PROJECT\\"],\\"ending\\":[\\"\\\\\\"anamnesis\\\\\\" by Annabel\\"]}\', \'https://www.youtube.com/embed/UGoAl3L13bc?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque&autoplay=1\', \'{\\"from\\":\\"2012-01-10T00:00:00+00:00\\",\\"to\\":\\"2012-03-27T00:00:00+00:00\\",\\"details\\":{\\"from\\":{\\"day\\":10,\\"month\\":1,\\"year\\":2012},\\"to\\":{\\"day\\":27,\\"month\\":3,\\"year\\":2012}},\\"data\\":\\"Jan 10, 2012 to Mar 27, 2012\\"}\', false, \'24 min per ep\', \'R - 17+ (violence & profanity)\', 7.51, 1631599252606, 2)'
}
```

but I don't know what's wrong, so i ask here. Thanks. I'll provide other info if needed.

Answer (score 0):

stupid of me, i forgot to convert the arrays into string, so the query messed up. if somebody have similar issue with this, i recommend to check your data before inserting, if any of the data is array make sure to convert it to string.